# Object that is used for Case Feed comments

Tags: relationships, childrelationship, case-comment, feedcomment

I'd like to create a trigger that fires every time a user, either internal or an external community user, comments on a case. Here is my comment

[image]

I do know that the `CaseFeed` object is used because when I do this SOQL, `SELECT Id, CommentCount, Body FROM CaseFeed`, this is the result.

[image]

It looks like I'll be able to create a trigger on the `CaseFeed` object, but I'd also like to create a trigger on the comments of a case feed. I can't find what that object is. I thought it could be the `CaseComment` object, but when I do a SOQL on that object, nothing is return. `SELECT Id, CommentBody FROM CaseComment`

[image]

Which object is used for the comments on a Case Feed record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CaseComment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/CaseComment) is the classic "Case Comment" object, not related to feed items at all. You're looking for [FeedComment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/FeedComment), which contains comments on feed items.

Comment: IMO, the sObject names are not intuitive 

Comment: @TylerZika That's because of historical reasons--Chatter is newer than cases. If they'd all been designed at the same time, it would probably be a different story.